# How to make method in view execute after method in view model is execute?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, devexpress

```
// view model
public void CreateChildViewModel()
{
 //do something
}
//view
_fluent.WithCommand(x => x.CreateChildViewModel()).After(PreviewObject);
private void PreviewObject()
{
 //do somthing
 // this method is not call because method CreateChildViewModel is not bind with any control 
 //in view but it's was called automatically when child view-model is created
 }
```

so how can I call PreviewObject method after method CreateChildViewModel finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**

This breaks [`MVVM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) pattern.

Regardless, you will need to hold a reference to your `View` or use a `Delegate` or `Action` depending who had the responsibility for creating and originally showing it. Then some how coupling this all together by passing the `Reference` `Action` or `Delegate` to the view model.

**However**

I would seriously consider your design an decide whether your `ViewModel` really needs to access the views Code Behind (as this seems a little unusual) and trying to push this responsibility back to the `ViewModel`.

**Lastly**

If this is really what you need to do, it seems like a good candidate for a decoupled messaging or event aggregator system as is found in various MVVM frameworks like MVVMLight

**Additional Resouces**

[MVVM Light Messenger](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger)

[Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)